# Create a random number and check if it is odd or even

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, random

I am looking to create a batch file that, when ran, creates a random integer from 0 to 100 and then runs it through an if statement that checks whether it is odd or even. 
I've been having some trouble, so here is what I have so far.

```
@echo off
set /a num=%random% %%100 +1
if ( num % 2 == 0 ) {
     //even
}
else
{
    //odd
}
```

The error I get is - "num was unexpected at this time"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set /a num=%random% %%100 +1
SET /a nummod2=num %% 2
IF %nummod2% == 0 (ECHO %num% is even) ELSE (ECHO %num% is odd)

GOTO :EOF
```

Conventional `IF` syntax is `if [not] operand1==operand2 somethingtodo` where operand1 and operand2 are both strings. If the strings contain separators like <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or other characters that have a special meaning to batch then the string must be `"enclosed in quotes"`.

Fundamentally, `if` compares *strings*. The operator must be one of a fixed set of operators [== equ neq gtr geq lss leq] hence `cmd` was objecting to `num` where it expected an operator.

A calculation cannot be performed within a `if` statement's parameters.

`%%` is required to perform the `mod` operation, since `%` is a special character that itself needs to be escaped by a `%`.

Note that `{` and `}` are ordinary characters with no special meaning to batch and remarks must follow

```
rem remark string
```

There is a commonly-used exploit which is

```
::comment
```

actually, a broken label, which can have unforeseen side-effects (like ending a code-block)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but since I'm quite new to the batch scene, what does the GOTO :EOF mean at the end of your code? I read on google that - "Using GOTO:eof will always transfer execution to the end of the current batch file or the end of the current subroutine. " What does this mean?

Comment: Batch executes instructions line by line until it eaches either the end of physical file or an `exit` statement. Batch can also use subroutines which are customarily placed at the end of the file. I put the `goto` line there because that way I can be sure that if I add a subroutine to the code, the main part won't run into the subroutine. Just a habit. In this example, it's not required. It's very specific - the colon *must* be included and it very specifically means "go to the physical end of file." Reaching EOF terminates the batch or if it's encountered in a subroutine, ends the subroutine.

Comment: Actually, this code generates a number from 1 to 100 instead of 0 to 100. It should use `set /a num=%random% %%101`

Answer (score 0):

The following prints a random number between 0 and 99, and prints whether it's even or odd:

```
@echo off

set /a num = %random% %% 100
echo %num%
set /a odd = num %% 2
if %odd% EQU 1 (echo odd) else (echo even)
```